# Spurious calls to setValueAt with JTables in Java 7 on OS X Lion?

Tags: java, swing, osx-lion, java-7

After upgrading to Lion, and Java 7, I am running into issues with JTables. When I use arrow keys to move the selection around, its calling `setValueAt()` with empty strings as the edit value.

To test this, I created a simple JFrame with a table in it, and set the following class as its model.

```
public class SpyModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    public int getColumnCount() { return 5; }
    public int getRowCount() { return 5; }
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) { return ""; }
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) { return true; }

    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        System.out.println(aValue == null ? "null" : "\"" + aValue + "\"");
    }
}
```

When I run it under Java 6, and then use the arrow keys to move through it. it works fine. e.g.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03-424-11M3720)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)
$ java -jar JavaApplication5.jar
```

However, when I run it under Java 7 (on Lion), and move the selection with the arrow keys, it ends up calling `setValueAt()` with empty strings.

e.g.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
$ java -jar JavaApplication5.jar 
""
""
""
""
""
$
```

I've searched for bugs, but I haven't come up with anything. Is this a known problem?

Comment: I've submitted this as a bug: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7185868

Comment: The bug is not fixed in the latest JDK 7 (release 9). The bug report is no longer visible, and Apple's latest JDK 6 push makes Java 7 the default *and* removes the java preferences app. Fun times.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is more then one bug when playing with that table example.

I used the following SSCCE which works as expected under JDK1.6

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableBugDemo {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame( "TestFrame" );
    final JTable table = new JTable( new SpyModel() );
    table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener( new ListSelectionListener() {
      @Override
      public void valueChanged( ListSelectionEvent e ) {
        Thread.dumpStack();
        System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());
      }
    } );
    frame.add( table );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible( true );
  }

  public static class SpyModel extends DefaultTableModel{
    public SpyModel() {
      super( new String[][]{
          new String[]{ "row1-1", "row1-2", "row1-3"},
          new String[]{ "row2-1", "row2-2", "row2-3"},
          new String[]{ "row3-1", "row3-2", "row3-3"},
          new String[]{ "row4-1", "row4-2", "row4-3"},
      }, new String[]{"col1", "col2", "col3"});
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt( Object aValue, int row, int column ) {
      System.out.println( "TableBugDemo$SpyModel.setValueAt" );
      Thread.dumpStack();
      super.setValueAt( aValue, row, column );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable( int row, int column ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Under JDK1.7 however:

- I see the `setValueAt` being called when making the table editable. However, not with an empty string but with the actual values which are contained in my `TableModel`. This means that nothing is changed to my data. Only annoying thing is that during the navigation my table is constantly updating. Workaround is of course to adjust the `setValueAt` method with a quick exit path when the value is not updated at all, e.g adding

  ```
  if ( ( aValue != null && aValue.equals( getValueAt( row, column ) ) ) ||
       ( aValue == null && getValueAt( row, column ) == null ) ){
    return;
  }
  ```
- Navigating with the up and down arrows make the selection jump 2 rows at a time. Stacktraces reveal the change in selection originates from the `BasicTableUI#Actions` class (which makes sense as that is the action which is placed in the action map). The weird thing is that for one key-press this action is triggered twice. That already explains why the selection jumps 2 rows at a time. Further debugging revealed that for hitting my arrow key once I received two distinct `KEY_PRESSED` events. As far as I can tell, those event are placed like that on the `EventQueue` and have nothing to do with the `JTable`. Just to make sure, I created a small SSCCE which does not include a `JTable`:

  ```
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
   import java.awt.AWTEvent;
   import java.awt.EventQueue;
   import java.awt.Toolkit;
   import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
   import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

   public class KeyEventBugDemo {
     public static void main( String[] args ) {
       EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
           JFrame testframe = new JFrame( "testframe" );
           testframe.setSize( 300,300 );
           testframe.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
           testframe.setVisible( true );
         }
       } );
       Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener( new AWTEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void eventDispatched( AWTEvent event ) {
           if (event instanceof KeyEvent ){
             KeyEvent keyevent = ( KeyEvent ) event;
             System.out.println( "keyevent.getKeyCode() = " + keyevent.getKeyCode() );
             System.out.println( "ID = " + System.identityHashCode( keyevent ) );
             System.out.println( "keyevent = " + keyevent );
           }
         }
       }, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK );
     }
   }
  ```

Giving focus to the frame and then hitting the DOWN_ARROW results in the following output (stripped the output of `toString` to keep it readable)

```
keyevent.getKeyCode() = 40
ID = 960135925
keyevent = java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=40,...
keyevent.getKeyCode() = 40
ID = 1192754471
keyevent = java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=40,...
keyevent.getKeyCode() = 40
ID = 2012032999
keyevent = java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=40,...
```

Here you can clearly see that you get two `KEY_PRESSED` events which confuse the `JTable`. This does not occur when using a regular character key

```
keyevent.getKeyCode() = 65
ID = 1023134153
keyevent = java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=65,keyText=A,
ID = 914147942
keyevent = java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_TYPED,keyCode=0,keyText=Unknown 
keyevent.getKeyCode() = 65
ID = 986450556
keyevent = java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=65,keyText=A,keyChar='a',
```

Looking at the javadoc in the `KeyEvent` class:

> KEY_TYPED (is only generated if a valid Unicode character could be generated.)

it makes sense I won't get the `KEY_TYPED` event when hitting the arrow, but that it fires the `KEY_PRESSED` twice is in my opinion a bug (will log a bug report later on for this). A workaround might be to intercept such an event and not pass it through the chain but that sounds like an ugly hack to me.

*EDIT*

Another weird thing. If you add the following line to the snippet

```
table.getInputMap( JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT ).
  put( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( 'a' ), "selectNextRow" );
```

you can use the `a` to jump to the next line (same action as which is triggered by default by using the DOWN_ARROW). Due to the correct sequence of events when pressing `a`, it seems the `setValueAt` method is also not called. This makes me think that the two `KEY_PRESSED` events starts the editing somehow ...

Comment: Very interesting that you see it called with the original value and the double key event. I just reran my application (not example), and confirmed the original behaviour. `setValueAt()` is called with an empty string, and I did not observe the double key event.  Running your example, I get the replace with same string behavior, but not the double key event. I put the table in a scroll pane and called setCellSelectionEnabled(true) on the table to make it truer to the application.

Comment: I have this with `build 1.7.0_04-ea-b11` (the JDK that you get by default)

Comment: @Bill I added a small edit. Looks like the `setValueAt` call is related directly to the two `KEY_PRESSED` events on my machine

Comment: I can't check now, but last night I think I noticed (with cell selection enabled) that the spurious calls to `setValueAt` only occurs when moving up/down and not left/right. *edit* BTW, I'm on the latest download now. u09 IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this is to use:

```
putClientProperty("JTable.autoStartsEdit", Boolean.FALSE);
```

But in this case you will not be able to start editing in a cell by direct typing. You will have to use the mouse to start editing. I have also issued a bug to Oracle https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=9006933 but it is also not available... seems they are having a problem with the system.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't really do.

Answer (score 0):

Jut an update I still see this problem with 1.7.0_40 as I move around my JTable cells with cursor keys it causes it to blank out every field in goes into.

Adding:

```
table.putClientProperty("JTable.autoStartsEdit", Boolean.FALSE)
```

stops that issue happening, but then I have to press 'Enter' key to start editing.

Instead at the the start of your Jtables model you check for empty strings and return will workaround the problem

i.e.

```
 if(Platform.isOSX())
        {
            if(value.equals(""))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

but this does mean that if the user actually wants to empty the field that the change will be rejected. In my own application that isnt such a problem because I have a separate deleteField() action that they use.

The issue can be found in the OpenJdk bug tracker here

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8025126

and currently isn't due for fixing until Jdk 9