# Netbeans 7.2 based on JDK7 on Mac OS Mountain Lion crashes frequently

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.2

I am using the latest version of Netbeans (7.2) on a macbook pro with Mountain Lion clean installation, and it gives me frequent crashes.Is it only me , or is it a general problem and who is responsible for it mountain lion, netbeans or jdk7?

(The default java version for this machine is java 7 - you can set it in System Preferences->Java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say Java 7. I tried it briefly (on Lion) and it had severe issues. e.g. [Spurious calls to setValueAt with JTables in Java 7 on OS X Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553197/spurious-calls-to-setvalueat-with-jtables-in-java-7-on-os-x-lion)

I've been running Netbeans with Java 6 on Lion just fine.

IIRC, netbeans will log problems (exception etc...) you might want to look in your ~/.netbeans directory (exact name may vary) for things to submit to either Netbeans or as Java bugs to help.