# Work around navigation bug in JTable in OS X Java 7 (spurious calls to setValueAt with arrow keys)

Tags: macos, swing, jtable, java-7

I ran into this bug in Oracle's JDK 7 for OS X: [Spurious calls to setValueAt with JTables in Java 7 on OS X Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553197/spurious-calls-to-setvalueat-with-jtables-in-java-7-on-os-x-lion) The quick summary is that when you use the arrow keys to navigate through a JTable, `setValueAt()` gets called with empty strings. It's kind of disconcerting to watch your data disappear as you move through the table.

It is still unfixed, and Oracle has vanished the bug report that I filed. How can I work around this?

Ideally, I'd like it to simply not call `setValueAt()` at the wrong times, but if that can't be the case, I'd like find a work around that would allow the code in `setValueAt()` to understand that it has been called with no real edits made.

Unfortunately, I don't understand the workings of the events/methods in a JTable. So here is my (unfortunately vague) question. How can I work around this?

Comment: I added an answer in your other question. I can work around the `setValueAt` issue but have other issues ... seems like JDK7 has a few bugs in it. As mentioned in my answer there, I do not see data disappearing but I do see the calls to `setValueAt` which should't be needed

Comment: @Robin I feel it's more of a follow up.