# (Using Leiningen or Choosing a JVM) on OS X

Tags: clojure, jvm, osx-lion, leiningen

I want to try out Clojure and I'm having some trouble with the first step from [here](https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans).  It suggests using Leiningen to set up the Clojure project.

I download and run `lein` and I see this:

```
Error: dl failure on line 732
Error: failed /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/OpenJDK-1.7.0-20110203.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/client/libjvm.dylib, because dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/OpenJDK-1.7.0-20110203.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/client/libjvm.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/OpenJDK-1.7.0-20110203.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/client/libjvm.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Through some research I've discovered that this copy of libjvm.dylib is built for x86.  I suspect I need one that's built for x86_64.  I've downloaded and installed a new jvm.  You can see them here:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (7):
    1.7.0_b126+, x86_64:    "OpenJDK 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/OpenJDK-1.7.0-20110203.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_b126+, i386:  "OpenJDK 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/OpenJDK-1.7.0-20110203.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_12, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_12.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_43-b01-447, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_43-b01-447, i386: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_26-b03-383, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_26-b03-383.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_26-b03-383, i386: "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_26-b03-383.jdk/Contents/Home
```

The copy of libjvm.dylib I want to use is in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_12.jdk/...`

But I don't know how to tell leiningen to use this.  I actually don't think it's leiningen, but whatever that file is using to download something.  And whatever this something is insists on using `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/OpenJDK-1.7.0-20110203.jdk/`, even if I change JAVA_HOME or rename this directory to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk.old.foo`.

Comment: Once you get leiningen installed, it's quite nice to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 7 on the Mac is still pretty [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553197/spurious-calls-to-setvalueat-with-jtables-in-java-7-on-os-x-lion) (at least for my purposes), and even having it on the machine can mess up the Apple provided Java 6 that normally works just fine. Remove all Java 7 installations (possibly log out/reboot) and then see if Java 6 will run (type java -version) from the command line. If you see something like this:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_43"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01-447-11M4203)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01-447, mixed mode)
```

If you do, then you're good to go. After I removed JDK 7, I was able to continue on with my [Clojure work](http://www.warscore.net) on my mac.

Comment: I didn't need to uninstall java 7 (yet), but I did link /usr/bin/java to java1.6 and then lein installed easily.

Comment: Good to hear. There was something going on on my machine that interfered with Swing apps starting. Removing Java 7 (well, mostly) took care of that.

Answer (score -1):

Double check these steps:

1. Copy lein to /usr/bin/lein
2. chmod 755 /usr/bin/lein
3. lein repl